# What's the meaning of 一度 in this sentence?

Tags: phrases

I don't think 一度 means "once" in this sentence. Thus, I would to know if there is any other meaning in 一度 that I am missing here:

羽原と一度性交するたびに、彼女はひとつ興味深い、不思議な話を聞かせてくれた。

Answer (score 3):

This 一度 does mean "once" or "one time". There's nothing mysterious.

- 一度Xするたびに: For every one time I do X / For each time I do X
- 二度Xするたびに: For every two times I do X / Whenever I do X twice
- ...and so on.

一度 is technically redundant when you just want to say "For each time", but adding 一度 makes the sentence more explicit and emphatic ("For each *single* time").